# On the series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos nx}{\Gamma\left ( a+n+1 \right ) \Gamma \left ( a-n+1 \right )}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions

For the values of $a$ for which the following series makes sense, prove that

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos nx}{\Gamma\left ( a+n+1 \right ) \Gamma \left ( a-n+1 \right )} = \frac{\left ( 2 \cos \frac{x}{2} \right )^{2a}}{\Gamma\left ( 2a+1 \right )}$$

I ran into this series recently and I have no idea how to attack it. How would you go to prove the identity?

Comment: It is just the Fourier cosine series of $\left(2\cos\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2a}=\left(e^{ix/2}+e^{-ix/2}\right)^{2a}$, so it is enough to apply the extended binomial theorem and express the binomials through the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Ah, wow! If we don’t know the result ? Is there a direct way of calculating it ?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(a+n+1)\Gamma(a-n+1)}=\frac{1}{(a+n)!(a-n)!}=\frac{1}{(2a)!}\binom{2a}{a+n}$$ and $$\cos(nx)=\text{Re}\left(e^{inx}\right)$$ plus the extended binomial theorem.

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks Jack! You enlightened me!!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, following Jack's comment we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos nx}{\Gamma\left ( a+n+1 \right ) \Gamma \left ( a-n+1 \right )}   &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos nx}{\left ( a+n \right )! \left ( a-n \right )!} \\ 
 &=\frac{1}{\left (2a  \right )!}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \binom{2a}{a+n} \cos nx   \\ 
 &=\frac{1}{\left (2a  \right )!}\mathfrak{Re} \left ( \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \binom{2a}{a+n} e^{inx} \right ) \\ 
 &= \frac{\left ( 2 \cos \frac{x}{2} \right )^{2a}}{\left ( 2a \right )!} \\
 &= \frac{\left ( 2 \cos \frac{x}{2} \right )^{2a}}{\Gamma\left ( 2a+1 \right )}
\end{align*}

from the [extended binomial theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Theorem/Extended).

Comment: [+1] very efficient ! Once again, Jack D'Aurizio had the good way...

Comment: A remark : once the LHS and RHS have been multiplied by $\Gamma(2a+1)$, letting $a \to \infty$ (by taking integer even values), the obtained expression converges to a Dirac comb.